# Using Sentry for non-standard programming language

Tags: sentry

Can Sentry be used for logging errors/warnings from
non-standard programming language environment? We are maintaining a GIS that uses a proprietrary programming language and we are struggling with a more smooth error handling.

I was wondering if the API can be used to push errors/exceptions/warnings to Sentry.

Answer (score 3):

To report to Sentry you’ll need to use a language-specific SDK. The Sentry team builds and maintains these for most popular languages, but there’s also a large ecosystem supported by the community.

**If your use-case is very specific, or not covered by Sentry**, you’ll find documentation on how to report events on your own using their [SDK API](https://docs.sentry.io/development/sdk-dev/).